# Install fitter package in python

Tags: python

I've been using python for some time now but I haven't installed any external packages that are not include in anaconda. Now I want to install fitter 1.0.8 package in python 2.7.10.  I have anaconda 2.3.0 downloaded (64 bit) on windows and I'm working on spyder. So far I have tried to install it from the Anaconda command Prompt. I tried to right-click the tar.gz hyperlink and click "Copy Link Address" and I got https://pypi.python.org/packages/78/d8/6c41c8aa704994998564a41f2570b72f755431adab05f401908cab7c6de8/fitter-1.0.8.tar.gz. Then I typed in the anaconda command prompt:

```
pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/78/d8/6c41c8aa704994998564a41f2570b72f755431adab05f401908cab7c6de8/fitter-1.0.8.tar.gz
```

and I got access denied for some of the folders of the package. Any help would be vary much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running this command in a cmd that you chose to run as admin? Also when you installed Anaconda, did you do so as admin?

Comment: I'm not sure how to test this. My question might sound stupid but is there any difference between installing the package at the anaconda command prompt or the windows command prompt?

Comment: I sorted this out at the end. It was a problem with the admin rights I have indeed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can install it via pip command:

```
pip install fitter
```